# MongoLab - can't get objects from DB

Tags: javascript, http, get, mlab

I would like to get some objects from a collection in mongolab, and this is my function with the query:

```
$scope.getMethods = function ()
    {
        var getList = $http.get("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/timeman/collections/Methods",
            { params : 
               { apiKey : apiKeyString,
                  q : JSON.stringify({ "project_id" : '"' + $scope.project_id +'"'})
               }
            }

        );
        getList.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.projectMethods = data;

        }); 
        getList.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           throw new Error("Something got wrong with get");
        });
    };
```

alternatively, I tried also this way

```
var getList = $http.get("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/timeman/collections/UCD_Methods?",
              + apiKeyString + '&q={"project_id":"' + $scope.project_id + '"}', {});
```

The problem is that in both cases, the address is not interpreted correctely: in fact, I can't retrieve the objects and in the console of my browsers you can see that after "q=" the quotes are interpreted like this %22 (I replaced the apiKey with dots):

```
[22:39:13.951] GET https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/timeman/collections/Methods?apiKey=...&q=%7B%22project_id%22:%2252aee85ae4b01e4b6836c226%22%7D [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 577ms]
```

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: the % symbols are just HTML URL encoding: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp. the HTTP response suggests that the request is going through. what is the output you're receiving?

Comment: also, feel free to e-mail us directly at support@mongolab.com

Comment: Thank you Chris, actually it was a VERY VERY stupid error: the name of the collection was written wrong in the code.... beginners error! Thanks for the patience!